# Just installed CakePHP, where to go now with creating a user system?

Tags: php, cakephp-1.3

I've been putting this off for almost 6 months now. I kept telling myself that I will upgrade my website to CakePHP and put in a user system. Well, I finally took the first step by installing CakePHP (It's a small step, but I am proud that I finally did it). Anyways, I want a user system, and I don't know where to go from here. I won't mind creating one myself, but I would need a little direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not stated the complexity of the user system you're after. However, the following are fairly [straightforward](http://ertw.com/blog/2007/11/04/a-simple-authentication-system-with-cakephp-12-and-auth-component/) [authentication](http://book.cakephp.org/view/172/Authentication) [systems](http://www.studiocanaria.com/articles/cakephp_auth_component_users_groups_permissions) for CakePHP.

Comment: If you are simply starting out with PHP, jumping into a framework may, arguably, not be the best choice. However, if you can follow the logic behind the code than by all means dive in head first, you have everything to learn =)